# cell2mat not supported for C code generation in MATLAB Coder

Tags: matlab, code-generation, matlab-deployment

I am trying to convert a neural network function written in MATLAB to C function by using MATLAB Codel APP. But when I try to convert, I am getting as

> cell2mat is not supported for code generation arrayfun is not supported for code generation

How can I replace these functions?

My code is as given below. Input `X` is a 1x2500 matrix and `output` is a 1x6 matrix.

Full code is aavailable in this link [boneGrwNN](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1BXcWHP3jhpZTQz8tQ9-nAYjVcI80qSoF)

```
function Y = boneGrwNN(X)
x1_step1.ymin = -1;    
% ===== SIMULATION ========    
% Format Input Arguments
isCellX = iscell(X);
if ~isCellX, X = {X}; end;    
% Dimensions
TS = size(X,2); % timesteps
if ~isempty(X)
    Q = size(X{1},1); % samples/series
else
    Q = 0;
end    
% Allocate Outputs
Y = cell(1,TS);    
% Time loop
for ts=1:TS        
    % Input 1
    X{1,ts} = X{1,ts}';
    Xp1 = mapminmax_apply(X{1,ts},x1_step1);        
    % Layer 1
    a1 = tansig_apply(repmat(b1,1,Q) + IW1_1*Xp1);        
    % Layer 2
    a2 = softmax_apply(repmat(b2,1,Q) + LW2_1*a1);        
    % Output 1
    Y{1,ts} = a2;
    Y{1,ts} = Y{1,ts}';
end   
% Format Output Arguments
if ~isCellX, Y = cell2mat(Y); end
end

% ===== MODULE FUNCTIONS ========    
% Map Minimum and Maximum Input Processing Function
function y = mapminmax_apply(x,settings)
y = bsxfun(@minus,x,settings.xoffset);
y = bsxfun(@times,y,settings.gain);
y = bsxfun(@plus,y,settings.ymin);
end    
% Competitive Soft Transfer Function
function a = softmax_apply(n,~)
if isa(n,'gpuArray')
    a = iSoftmaxApplyGPU(n);
else
    a = iSoftmaxApplyCPU(n);
end
end
function a = iSoftmaxApplyCPU(n)
nmax = max(n,[],1);
n = bsxfun(@minus,n,nmax);
numerator = exp(n);
denominator = sum(numerator,1);
denominator(denominator == 0) = 1;
a = bsxfun(@rdivide,numerator,denominator);
end
function a = iSoftmaxApplyGPU(n)
nmax = max(n,[],1);
numerator = arrayfun(@iSoftmaxApplyGPUHelper1,n,nmax);
denominator = sum(numerator,1);
a = arrayfun(@iSoftmaxApplyGPUHelper2,numerator,denominator);
end
function numerator = iSoftmaxApplyGPUHelper1(n,nmax)
numerator = exp(n - nmax);
end
function a = iSoftmaxApplyGPUHelper2(numerator,denominator)
if (denominator == 0)
    a = numerator;
else
    a = numerator ./ denominator;
end
end

% Sigmoid Symmetric Transfer Function
function a = tansig_apply(n,~)
a = 2 ./ (1 + exp(-2*n)) - 1;
end
```

How can I generate C code for this function ?

Comment: If you understand what `cell2mat` does, and you understand the inputs you are passing it, then why can't you manually replicate the behaviour without using `cell2mat` itself?

Answer (score 0):

You can generate standalone `C` code only from [functions supported by code generation](https://mathworks.com/help/simulink/ug/functions-supported-for-code-generation-alphabetical-list.html). If you really need `C` code because your environment doesn't support Matlab, then you have to manually convert unsupported functions or use `coder.ceval` in order to use external `C` code that implements the same functions.

In your example, you could replace `arrayfun` calls with traditional `for-loops`. In order to implement your own `cell2mat` code, just type `open cell2mat` so see the source code of the function and try to replicate its logics within your code.